# Is it possible to let people approve their own pull requests if nothing but a bug workitem is linked?

Tags: azure, azure-devops, devops, azure-policy

In my current company, we are sometimes approving our own pull requests for the sake of bugfixing. If it's a small bug, or someone has breakdown service, they are required to be able to fix things quickly.

Because some people abuse this functionality to approve their own 'features', I wish to remove the ability to do this, except if the there are only 'bug' workitems linked to the PR.

As far as I have seen, I can only check some marks regarding the policy of the masterbranch.

Can I create a policy to enable people to approve their own pull requests, if no work-items other than bug items are linked to it?

Comment: don't think it's possible

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's not supported in Azure Pipelines - it's either allowed or not based on your branch policies. Everything that follows is opinion, so take it with a grain of salt - I'm not convinced that such a feature would solve your problem.

You said that you currently allow developers to approve their changes because, if there's an urgent bug they need to be able to move quickly. That's understandable. Also, developers can "game the system" by PR'ing features.

If you were to restrict branch policy to allow developers to merge PR's only if bugs are attached, what prevents the developer from putting new feature functionality into bug fixes?

In other words, your PR policies work by convention, and that convention can be broken. Your proposed solution is another convention that can be broken.